# How to prevent Numba from parallelizing a particular loop when parallel=True is used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, numba

I have a test code like so:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
import random


def func():
    a = np.empty(0)
    for i in range(10):
        b = np.arange(np.random.randint(10))
        a = np.concatenate((a, b))
        print(len(b), ' / ', len(a))


func()
```

It works as expected:

```
3  /  3
6  /  9
5  /  14
8  /  22
9  /  31
6  /  37
9  /  46
5  /  51
3  /  54
9  /  63
```

If I compile with Numba by adding `@njit(parallel=True)` decorator, it stops working because Numba parallelizes this loop which causes issues:

```
2  /  0
1  /  0
2  /  0
7  /  0
0  /  0
3  /  0
2  /  0
5  /  0
7  /  0
2  /  0
```

In my real code there is another loop in this function which uses prange, so I want parallel=True on the whole function. But I don't want it for this loop.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up splitting this portion of the code out of the `@njit`'ed function which had `parallel=True`, and on this function that was factored out I used `@njit` but left `parallel=False`

This did it for me.

Comment: Yes I had the same question but could not figure out how to tell Numba how to not make a particular loop parallel either.  I suppose moving it into a separate function will always work, good idea.